# Hide data in url when using window.open in jquery

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i was performed onclick to download pdf in below there is my jQuery code

```
  $("#mlt_voucher").on("click", function () {
        var checkedId = [];
        var deduction = $('#dynamicmodel-deduction_type').val();
        // alert(deduction);
        $.each($("input:checkbox[class=chkItem]:checked"), function(){
            checkedId.push($(this).attr("id"));
            
        });
        window.open('$deductiondown?checkedId='+checkedId+'&deduction='+deduction, '_blank');
       
        });
```

there is the url look like
http://localhost/fads/admin/master-beneficiary/deductiondown?checkedId=29155,29152&deduction=1

**i want hide my data in that url what can i do for that ?**
and also i don't want to use that code in below

```
 $("#mlt_voucher").on("click", function () {
    var checkedId = [];
    var deduction = $('#dynamicmodel-deduction_type').val();
    alert(deduction);
    $.each($("input:checkbox[class=chkItem]:checked"), function(){
        checkedId.push($(this).attr("id"));
        
    });
    
    $.post(
        '$deductiondown',
        { checkedId:checkedId,deduction:deduction},
        // function(response){
        //     // console.log(response);
        //     location.reload();
        // }
    ); 
    });
```

Comment: If your script _needs_ the data, then you can not actually "hide" it. At most you could put it into the session on the server-side beforehand, and then only send an identifier that allows you to pick the correct values from the session.

Comment: there is my second code that help to hide my data but not open in new tab and there is some problem that way i can't  use that session method  i already know about this

Comment: i only want to know that i can use that 2 thing (post and window.open) at the same time in same jQuery

Comment: _"but not open in new tab"_ - of course it doesn't. You are making a background request there, that doesn't open "in" any tabs at all; and `location.reload` of course does not open any new tabs either. Plus, even if you opened a new tab at that point, the data you just POSTed won't be available in _that_ request again - at this point you'd need a session again, to store the data send with that first request, so that it is still available to the second one.

Comment: _"can use that 2 thing (post and window.open) at the same time"_ - use a normal form, method POST, put your data into hidden fields, add a `target` attribute to the form, and automatically submit it using JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe thank you now i got it there is no way to use that 2 thing at the same time now without hide i send my data and also open in new tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251682/discussion-between-bhavesh-sahu-and-cbroe).